# Hacer CRUD con Python a SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, crud

Estoy desarrollando un script sencillo para bajar unos datos a una DB lo que tengo es esto:

{

```
import sqlite3, time

print "Sistema Cargas minutas"
print "Version 0.1"

conn = sqlite3.connect('db_pagos_minuta.sqlite3')
cur = conn.cursor()
salir = 's'

while salir != 'n':
   print "Carga de nuevo requerimiento"
   nombre = raw_input("Introduzca nombre y apellido: ")
   cedula = raw_input("Introduzca numero de Cedula: ")
   cedula = int(cedula)
   datos = list()
   datos.append(cedula)
   datos.append(nombre)
   ''' nombre y cedula son las variables que al final iran a la bd '''
   cur.execute("insert into personas (nombre, cedula) values ( ? , ?)" , datos)
```

}

El problema es que despues de pasar la lista (o array) en la tabla de la BD no actualiza, y no da codigo de error o Traceback.

Comment: Has probado hacer un `conn.commit()` y un `conn.close()` para finalizar?

Comment: Como comenta Patricio debes hacer un `commit` o usar un estamento `with` para que los cambios se apliquen.

Comment: Gracias, despues de 20 minutos que hice la pregunta era lo que faltaba, ya lo hice y funciona.